# MVC 4 TreeView Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I tried to follow this, as it was quoted as an example in many places:

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx

and have come up with the following (a few alterations due to me using mvc4 not 2)

In the controller class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        MenuDBContext db = new MenuDBContext();
        ViewData["AllMenu"] = db.Menus.ToList();
        return View(db.Menus.ToList().Where(c => c.PId == null));

    }
```

The view class:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<Geo.Models.Menu> 

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <li>
          @item
          @{var children = ViewData["AllMenu"].Where(c => c.PId == item.Id);}
          @if (children.Count() > 0)
          {
              <ul>
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("ItemControl", children);}
             </ul>

          }
     </li>
   }
```

I can't for the life of me work out why I can't use .Where on ViewData["AllMenu"] or .Count() on children. Any tips on where I am going wrong would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast ViewData["AllMenu"] as IEnumerable<

```
var children = (ViewData["AllMenu"] as IEnumerable<GeomantApp.Models.Menu>).Where(c => c....
```

ViewData is `Dictionary<string,object>` so when you try and get a property from that dictionary, ASP.NET has no way of knowing what it is before hand so you get compiler errors if you don't cast your object first.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the count issue, however .Where still does not work, the only option shown is Enumerator, this doesn't make sense to me as it is fine to use .Where in the controller class?

Comment: `@{var menuItems = (ViewData["AllMenu"] as List<Geo.Models.Menu>);} @{var children = menuItems.Where(c => c.PId == item.Id);}` Works, but seems slightly sloppy. IEnumberable did not, but thanks for your help!